# group by many columns and calculate mean

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I'm working with hourly polutant data measured in various air quality stations. I want to have the daily average for all stations in one DF.

| date | site a | site b | site c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2010-01-01 01:00:00 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2010-01-01 02:00:00 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

and I would like:

| date | site a | site b | site c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-01-01 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

```
daylyavg <- df %>%
  group_by(Month, Day) %>%
  summarize(Avg_a = mean(site a))
```

| Month | day | Avg_a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Remember that in R it's better if the column names doesn't contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr::across`:

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)

my_data %>%
  mutate(date = ymd_hms(date)) %>%  # in case not already POSIXct date-time
  
  mutate(month = month(date),
         day = day(date)) %>%

  group_by(month, day) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("site"), mean,
                   .names = "Avg_{.col}")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
  month   day Avg_site.a Avg_site.b Avg_site.c
  <dbl> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1     1          2          2          2
```

Data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
        date = c("2010-01-01 00:00:00",
                 "2010-01-01 01:00:00","2010-01-01 02:00:00"),
      site.a = c(3L, 2L, 1L),
      site.b = c(2L, 2L, 2L),
      site.c = c(1L, 2L, 3L)
)
```